# Tagging books in a library database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I've got two tables, "books" and "tags". I have a third, "book_tags", that tracks which tags are given to which books. I realize there may be other setups that would work better, but let's just say it has to be this way.

```
books: isbn (PK), title, author, ...
tags: tag_name (PK)
book_tags: isbn (FK), tag (FK)
    (isbn, tag) form PK
```

Is it possible to write inserts for the book_tags table in such a way that any new tags will be automatically added to the tags table?

In case it's relevant, I'm using postgres 9.6.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What do you have so far?

Comment: Nothing. I'm a SQL noob trying to be too ambitious with a practice project.

Comment: Well the first step to getting a response is to at least post the structure of your tables and probably some sample data.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: @JNevill I thought that might be the case. I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: If the table tags only includes tag_name then what purpose does that table serve? (does table book_tags contain column tag_name rather than tag?)

Comment: I agree with @KevinPostlewaite It does seem a bit pointless to have a seperate table that just has distinct tag_names in it. Unless you intend to capture an attribute of the tag_name like `create_date` or something which you can do in the same trigger when you insert to that table.

Comment: Are tags unique?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Yes they are.

Comment: Then why dont you just create a tag colum in the books table and that should solve your problem. You dont need book_tags table it is irrelevant

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use triggers on the insert query. Check this
1. Create a function that adds new record to tags table whenever a new query is executed agains book_tags.
2. Create a trigger for each row on book_tags with the above

> `create table books(isbn int PRIMARY KEY, title varchar, author
>   varchar);`
>
> `create table tags(tag_name int PRIMARY KEY);`
>
> `create table book_tags(isbn int  references books(isbn), tag int
>   references tags(tag_name));`

1. Create function addtotags()

> ```
> create or replace function addtotags() returns trigger as $$                                                                                         
> begin                                                                                                                                                           
> insert into tags(tag_name) values(new.tag_name);                                                                                                                
> return new;                                                                                                                                                     
> end;$$                                                                                                                                                          
> language plpgsql;
> ```

2. Create a trigger execadd_to_tags:

> ```
> create trigger execadd_to_tags before insert on book_tags for each row
>         execute procedure addtotags();
> ```

```
insert into books(1,'abc','x');
insert into book_tags(1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into postgresql's trigger functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-trigger.html

You can create a trigger that whenever you insert/delete/update on a specific table you can run a function that can automatically do whatever you want.